# Reflection on glass at not the critical angle

Tags: visible-light

I observed many a time that the incident light ray, even not at the critical angle, suffers reflection. Can I know why?

Comment: Look up the Fresnel equations. There is always some reflexion of the light, even when incident at less than the critical angle with the normal to the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing light in the form of waves, you can compare to the similar phenomenon of sound.

When you scream to someone behind a glass separator, part of the sound comes back to you and part of it goes through the wall. This is because the crystal is susceptible of transmitting sound, i.e. it can vibrate rather elastically. Hence part of the sound will be transmitted, but part of the sound will return to you.

In a way all materials, even glass, will transmit the electromagnetic waves, but will also elastically return part of the light.

Comment: But not if an AR layer is applied.  Your answer would be more useful if you included the Fresnel equations and a simple discussion of half- or quarter-wave AR coatings.

Comment: Adding an AR layer complicates things unnecessarily.  First, they aren't perfect, second, their spectral range is limited, third, the OP seems to be asking about reflection from simple surfaces.